# What should an int function return if the input is invalid?

Tags: c, exception

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Error checking a function that returns an int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4776329/error-checking-a-function-that-returns-an-int)

I have an integer function that returns an integer in a wide range (in  C).
How should I handle invalid inputs? I mean what should it return if the input is invalid?
Sorry If this question is too basic. I'm not experienced and couldn't find the answer anywhere else.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4776329/error-checking-a-function-that-returns-an-int

Answer (score 2):

Depends on the value range. For example, if your function is only expected to return positive values on success, return -1 for an error. If it normally only returns values >0, then return 0 on error.

If it returns any possible value in the int range, then you may need a different approach, for example

```
bool GetValue(int inputValue, int *outResult);
```

where your function stores the result in `outResult`, or returns false if an error occurred.

Comment: @EboMike So -1 is a positive value now?

Comment: Obviously, I'm saying "if the possible return value upon successful completion of the function is positive". The idea is that you want to return a value on error that CANNOT possibly be returned had the function call been successful.

Comment: I would return -1 to indicate error always, even if 0 is not a valid value to return.  That way -1 always means error, and not sometimes -1 and other times 0.

Comment: @EboMike Oh wait, sorry. I misread it as "if you function _can_ only return positive values"

Comment: @Rafe Kettler, victor23k: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stdbool.h

Answer (score 0):

Does your output range into the negative numbers? If not, -1 is a reasonably standard code to return.  Where are you getting the input from?

Comment: the input comes from the user and the output does not range into negatives. But there are also other int functions that accept input from other functions and not the user. Should I terminate the program from a non-main int function? or should I check if the return value is -1 in the main and terminate from there?

Answer (score 0):

Where is this input coming from? I assume from a user or file. Forget whatever the goddamned C function wishes to return to a call, I recommend doing a check if the input is an int at the beginning of the function:

```
if (userinput/1.00 == (int)userinput)
     We have an integer! Rest of the function goes here...
else
     Do something else like abort the function and change the 'input'...
```

Please excuse any inefficient/incorrect code, I myself am I programming noob.

Answer (score 0):

There really isn't any standard way for all cases. -1 is a common "generic error" return value. You can also do a bunch of defines like this:

```
#define MEMORY_ERROR  1
#define OUT_OF_BOUNDS 2
#define ...           3
etc...
```

and then you can use do this:

```
int func()
{
  ...
  ...
  if(condition) {
    // Error handling
    return MEMORY_ERROR;
  }
  ...
  if(condition) {
    // Error handling
    return OUT_OF_BOUNDS;
  }
}
```

or something like it.

Answer (score 0):

my preference, when writing code in a language that lacks exception handling, is to always use the return value as an error indicator.

```
int get_value(int *value)
{
    if ( input_ok )
        *value = input;
        return 0;
    return -1;
}
```

this does not seem practical since it forces you to use intermediate variables to store function results, but it proved useful so many times to catch errors and handle them correctly (you can never rely on user input).

also, you should note that having a special value to show an error is not a good idea: you never know what will happen with your code. if later you want to add a new feature and unfortunately the special value is useful for this feature, what will you do ? write a new function with another special error value ? what if the input should cover the whole range of the return type ? if this is part of a bigger project, how can you make sure that every programmer that may use your function is aware of the special value ?

so err on the safe side: don't use a special value and use a dedicated error handling path.

*note that you can reverse the above code and write `int get_value(int *error);`*